Use of dominated convergence theorem in Manski (1985)
I'm confused by the use of the dominated convergence theorem (DCT) in Lemma 5 of Manski (1985) (see below). Note that $b = (\tilde{b}_1, \dots, \tilde{b}_{K-1}, b_K).$
Specifically:

I presume the limit used in the DCT is the infinity in the upper limit of the inner integral, and that the inner integral being uniformly bounded implies dominance by some integrable function?

I don't understand why continuity in $b$ of the inner integral is relevant here - I don't see anything about this in the DCT. Should continuity of $P(y \geq 0, \tilde{x}\tilde{b} + b_K x_K \geq 0)$ follow instead from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Finally, if the inner integral is continuous in $b$, then is $P(y \geq 0, \tilde{x}\tilde{b} + b_K x_K \geq 0)$ differentiable in $b$?



